# MySql alias same as column name

Tags: mysql, alias

Is this a bad practice having alias same as column name? It seems to work but I wonder will it lead to problems ?

```
SELECT SUM(foo) AS foo FROM {$table}
```

Comment: Simply No, but when you write total_foo, you can know at once what you wanted in the first place, when you look at code the next time in 10 years

Comment: Another thing to consider is that even after all the years I've been working with MySQL, I still am not 100% sure how MySQL would interpret `SELECT SUM(foo) AS foo .... ORDER BY foo` (since it allows referencing aliases from the SELECT in the ORDER BY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problems. That said it would probably read better(more easily understandable) if you name it something like totalfoo or sum_of_foo.

Answer (score 0):

It can cause problems if you try to to use formatting or aggregating functions for a column together with a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) or [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) clause for the same column.

Example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`value`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `value`,count(*) AS `count`
FROM fields_values
GROUP BY `value`
```

In that case the GROUP BY will use the table's `value` column instead of the 1 returned by the STR_TO_DATE. In other words your GROUP BY will not work as expected.